# SSL and JKS to TLS 1.2 client side

Tags: ssl, jetty, tls1.2, embedded-jetty, jks

I am running an old version of jetty that allows SSL TLS v1.0 and v1.1. I want to disable anything other than TLS 1.2 as there are security vulnerabilities with the other implementations.

Currently clients connect to the jetty server using SSL, without any jks file for java clients or any certs or pk12 equivalent for c#/.net clients.

My understanding of jks is that the client and server needs it, which isn't a vulnerability in itself as the alias and servers should not be available in the jks file.

So my question is when I enforce stricter security protocol TLS 1.2 do i need to provide the clients with jks/pk12 or whatever the windows equivalent is? If i dont change the code to allow trustAll etc?

Client(is a request running within jetty server 9.4) server and request code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "filename");
System.setProperty("java.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xyx")
ServletContextHandler context = 
ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
...
server.setPort(8080);
server.start();

//Then call is via apache server code

CLoseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createMinimal();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://server:8080/getLogisticsData");

...

httpClient.execute(httpGet), response -> {

   //format response
 }));
```

Comment: You are probably also running an older version of Java that allows TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 (current, not expired, [versions of Java do not allow those protocols](https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html)).   If security is important to you then you MUST keep up to date with your Java VM and Jetty version.

Comment: client running java 1.8 running requests in jetty server 9.4 see code above.

Comment: Those System properties have no impact on Jetty, it will not use them, look for them, or even reference them, in fact it actively avoids them.  The Jetty "Connectors" you have setup are where your SSL/TLS configurations live for the server side.

Comment: So if I have a client side Jetty server communicating with a server side Jetty server 9.4.x version with TLS 1.2 enabled as default will the above code still work because I think Ice seen exceptions before where it says "no matching cipher suites" or some other security exception?  Server side code has an sslsocketconnector with sslcontextfactory added to the server config and a truststore and keystone resource (and password) added to the sslcontextfactory

Comment: If you have a "sslsocketconnector" on Jetty then you have a very old version of Jetty (that class was replaced years ago with `ServerConnector`).   Server is one thing, client is a different thing, they live separately (except for Jetty's ProxyServlet).  Doesn't matter if they are on the same JVM or not.  Behavior and configuration are separate (except for Jetty's ProxyServlet which can share a common SslContextFactory).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks but thats not  the question i was asking.  I can change the server side jetty server code to be something like this `ServerConnect sslConnector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer, new SSLConnectionFactory(),new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));` or some such setup.   I cant touch the client side code, so i want to know if TLS 1.2 is enabled server side(jetty), can i still connect without a jks file from the client jetty server if i don't set the truststore/keystore client side?